# How to use different classes with only one LiveData list?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this interface and 2 classes, I know it's not the best approach here, but that's not the point now.

```
interface FilterItem {
    val id: String
    val name: String
    val isChecked: ObservableField<Boolean>
    fun reset()
}

data class Technology(
    override val id: String,
    override val name: String,
    override val isChecked: ObservableField<Boolean> = ObservableField(),
) : FilterItem {
    override fun reset() {
        isChecked.set(false)
    }
}

data class Project(
    override val id: String,
    override val name: String,
    override val isChecked: ObservableField<Boolean> = ObservableField(),
) : FilterItem {
    override fun reset() {
        isChecked.set(false)
    }
}
```

And then I have a ViewModel

```
private val _filterList = MutableLiveData<List<FilterItem>>().apply {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            value = loadSkills()
        }
    }
    val filterList: LiveData<List<FilterItem>>
        get() = _filterList
private fun loadSkills(): MutableList<FilterItem> {
        val technologiesList: MutableList<FilterItem> = mutableListOf()
        technologiesList.add(Technology("1", "Android"))
        technologiesList.add(Technology("2", "Kotlin"))
        return technologiesList
    }
    private fun loadProjects(): MutableList<FilterItem> {
        val projectsList: MutableList<FilterItem> = mutableListOf()
        projectsList.add(Project("1", "Project 1"))
        projectsList.add(Project("2", "Project 2"))
        return projectsList
    }
```

I want to use the filterList so that is holds a list of Technologies or a list of Projects, depending on what BottomSheetDialog I'm opening.

```
    showSkillsButton.setOnClickListener {
        showFilterModal(filterViewModel.filterList, SKILLS)
    }
    showProjectsButton.setOnClickListener {
        showFilterModal(filterViewModel.projects, PROJECTS)
    }
```

I want to somehow use filterList only(I had 2 lists for skills and projects, but it would be nice if I could replace them with only 1 filterList).

Is there any way to do this? Or what would be the best approach?

Comment: I am understanding your question that you are wanting LiveData to consist of 2 lists `loadSkills()` and `loadProjects()` independently of each other. Is that true?

Comment: Or do you just want your LiveData to return `List<FilterItem>` but still include 2 lists, `loadSkills` and `loadProject`. And you want when LiveData triggers, you want you to still distinguish those two lists. Because when returning the same list, you cannot distinguish those two lists when LiveData triggers the value.